# Keycloak-Admin-Client in a JPMS/Jigsaw Java 11 Maven application - Dependency Problems

Tags: java, maven, keycloak, java-platform-module-system

maybe someone has already figured that out or has some tips, I would be really thankful.

I'm trying to use the Keycloak-Admin-Client maven dependency in a modularized Java 11 application. The Application is modularized via JPMS/Jigsaw.

I'm using the version 9.0.2 of the Keycloak-Admin-Client.

```
<keycloak-admin-client.version>9.0.2</keycloak-admin-client.version>

<groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
<artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
<version>${keycloak-admin-client.version}</version>
```

My current Problem: 
`java.lang.module.FindException: Module javax.ws.rs.api not found, required by com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base`

But I already have this in my module-info and POM:

`requires java.ws.rs;`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The javax.ws.rs-api jar is also in my libs folder (module-path):

[module-path lib folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACeZc.png)

Some additional informations from the jackson-jaxrs-providers GitHub-Repo:

```
    requires static javax.ws.rs.api;
    requires static java.ws.rs;
    requires static jakarta.ws.rs.api;
```

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/blob/master/json/src/moditect/module-info.java

I hope my problem is understandable, please ask if more details are needed.

Thanks a lot and best regards.

Pierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the javax.ws.rs-api artifact Version 2.1 has a different artifact-id "java.ws.rs-api" not "javax.ws.rs-api".

In Version 2.0.1. are packages missing.
Version 2.1-m08 works.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
   <!-- pwi: JAX-RS 2.x has different artifact-id, "javax.ws.rs-api" and Version 2.0.1 has missing packages -->
   <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.1-m08</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You should be able to mark your own answers as accepted. Doing so might help others finding the correct solution when they are facing the same or a similar problem.